# when I use to ITelephony I got this getITelephony method not found error

Tags: android

Accessing hidden method Landroid/telephony/TelephonyManager;->getITelephony()Lcom/android/internal/telephony/ITelephony; (greylist-max-p, reflection, denied)
W/System.err: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getITelephony []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ITelephony is supported for API level below 28 android versions only...
If you use in API level 28 and above android version then this error will came